# Garbage Collection with jGit

Tags: java, git, garbage-collection, jgit

## Cleaning a jGit Repository

I am using jGit to store some data in a local repository and for retrieving previous versions of the data again. The repository gets quite large and I want to execute the garbage collection command in order to repack the repository and make the repository smaller. The command line git command for this task would be:

```
git gc --aggressive
```

How can I achieve this with jGit?

### Example Repository

```
user:~$ du -h  /tmp/Evaluation_Git_Repo/
4,0K    /tmp/Evaluation_Git_Repo/.git/branches
8,0K    /tmp/Evaluation_Git_Repo/.git/logs/refs/heads
12K /tmp/Evaluation_Git_Repo/.git/logs/refs
20K /tmp/Evaluation_Git_Repo/.git/logs
4,0K    /tmp/Evaluation_Git_Repo/.git/hooks
4,0K    /tmp/Evaluation_Git_Repo/.git/refs/tags
4,0K    /tmp/Evaluation_Git_Repo/.git/refs/heads
12K /tmp/Evaluation_Git_Repo/.git/refs
4,0K    /tmp/Evaluation_Git_Repo/.git/objects/99
4,0K    /tmp/Evaluation_Git_Repo/.git/objects/29
4,0K    /tmp/Evaluation_Git_Repo/.git/objects/01
4,0K    /tmp/Evaluation_Git_Repo/.git/objects/e7
4,0K    /tmp/Evaluation_Git_Repo/.git/objects/info
4,0K    /tmp/Evaluation_Git_Repo/.git/objects/a9
4,0K    /tmp/Evaluation_Git_Repo/.git/objects/ec
...
7,2M    /tmp/Evaluation_Git_Repo/.git/objects
7,2M    /tmp/Evaluation_Git_Repo/.git
7,3M    /tmp/Evaluation_Git_Repo/
```

### Example Code with jGit

This is the code snippet it use so far:

```
/**
 * Repacks the repository
 */
public void repackRepository(){
    Properties prop;

    try {
        this.git.gc().setAggressive(true).call();


        prop = this.git.gc().getStatistics();
        logger.info("GC");

    } catch (GitAPIException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This does not have any effect in the file system. What is the proper way to use the gc() command in jGit?

### Expected Outcome

I would expect the outcome of the gc() call to be similar to the manual execution.

```
user$ git gc --aggressive
Counting objects: 75, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (50/50), done.
Writing objects: 100% (75/75), done.
Total 75 (delta 24), reused 48 (delta 0)
```

Which gives

```
user:/tmp/Evaluation_Git_Repo$ du -h  /tmp/Evaluation_Git_Repo/
4,0K    /tmp/Evaluation_Git_Repo/.git/branches
8,0K    /tmp/Evaluation_Git_Repo/.git/info
12K /tmp/Evaluation_Git_Repo/.git/logs/refs/heads
16K /tmp/Evaluation_Git_Repo/.git/logs/refs
28K /tmp/Evaluation_Git_Repo/.git/logs
4,0K    /tmp/Evaluation_Git_Repo/.git/hooks
4,0K    /tmp/Evaluation_Git_Repo/.git/refs/tags
4,0K    /tmp/Evaluation_Git_Repo/.git/refs/heads
12K /tmp/Evaluation_Git_Repo/.git/refs
8,0K    /tmp/Evaluation_Git_Repo/.git/objects/info
152K    /tmp/Evaluation_Git_Repo/.git/objects/pack
164K    /tmp/Evaluation_Git_Repo/.git/objects
244K    /tmp/Evaluation_Git_Repo/.git
304K    /tmp/Evaluation_Git_Repo/
```

The manual execution creates one pack file and reduces space quite a bit.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried it with the example in my [jgit-cookbook](https://github.com/centic9/jgit-cookbook/blob/master/src/main/java/org/dstadler/jgit/porcelain/CollectGarbage.java).

It seems JGit does actually do the pack, the "4.0k" output of "df" indicates that these are now empty directories, if you do an ls of one of those, you will see that there are no files in there any more.

And there is a ´.git/objects/pack´ directory which contains the pack-files.